# Clonezilla Disk too Small when it isn't

Tags: gparted, dd, disk-image, clonezilla

I took a 320 gig hard drive, shrunk the partition for Windows to 40 gigabytes, and cloned the partition. I'm trying to restore onto a 250 gig drive. I keep getting either a failed partition table, or clonezilla asking if the disk is too small. I've disabled size checking and anything to do with partitioning. I've tried everything and I still can't figure this out. Even tried DD, but when creating the initial partition, gparted fails with "Not a block device, refusing to create...."

Any thoughts? I have yet to find an issue like this since my partition is shrunken.

Comment: You sure the image is only of the 40GB parition?

Comment: Yep. It shows 40 gb when I go to restore, but it then fails to create the partition table and asks if the disk is too small.

Comment: The bad news is it came from a larger hard drive so it isn't going to happen.  This is NOT locigal to me, but I have hit this wall before.  The only way to succeed is to do a partition copy and copy that specific partition.

Comment: Yea, I agree, that's not logical. I did use partition copy. I didn't copy the whole disk. Same thing?

Comment: copying a partition copy 1 part of the disk if the whole disk is 1 partition then it is nearly identical.  The biggest difference is if you have 2 or more partition then only 1 will be copied.  Also there are a couple small reserved areas that are not copied on a partition copy that are on a disk copy.

Comment: Here's the thing, I resized the main partition to 40 gigs and confirmed it was. Then copied that partition with the boot partition. I can confirm it works on a drive of equal size, but it should work no matter what considering I cloned the partition and not the drive. That's where my confusion lies. Am I just missing something? I'd find it hard to believe it can't copy onto a larger partition.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clonezilla won't clone to a smaller disk](https://superuser.com/questions/1361361/clonezilla-wont-clone-to-a-smaller-disk)